# Opening new Window from ViewModel using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, wpf, inversion-of-control

I've been following the quick tutorial on using Castle Windsor in MVVM WPF:
[TUTORIAL](http://app-code.net/wordpress/?p=641)

I've set everything up (as for the basics) but I came to the point of creating a new Window after a button click. This is where I got lost.

Basically, from what I learned, the container should NOT be referenced more than once.

```
public class Shell : IShell
{
    public MainWindow window { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        window.Show();
    }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    IWindsorContainer container;
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

        // Resolve Shell to start application
        var start = container.Resolve<IShell>();
        start.Run();
        container.Release(start);
    }
}
```

I have it already referenced here, on application startup, so that my MainWindow is displayed and everything is properly attached to this.

Thus, my question is:

> How do I manage creation and showing of a new window, when this process i going to be initialized in a ViewModel?

The only thing that I was able to come up with was to:

1. Include all my Views in that very Shell described above, write methods there for creation of every window (just like Run() works)
2. Create a ContainerManager? that subscribes to events and push the code that is currently in my App class there and extend it so that it resolves container's shell everytime I need to create a new window and call an apropriate method to display a window.

The thing about solution above, is that it feels very wrong to me and feels like I would break a lot of principles here.